# Mysql search in json data using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

Suppose I have this json data stored in my MySQL DB:

```
{"cape":13,"vest":68,"stakk":68,"forkle":13}
```

I want to find if there is a key with the **exact** value of 6 or 28.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE logistic_config REGEXP ':6|:28'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM eorder_product WHERE logistic_config REGEXP '^.*(:6|:28).*$'
```

but it also finds the products that have a value of 68 like the example above.

Comment: try `REGEXP '(?=(?:\b6\b|\b28\b))'`

Comment: this works in JavaScript ... see if the regex helps you  `let str = '{"cape":13,"vest":67,"stakk":28,"forkle":13}';
let result = /(?=(?:\b6\b|\b28\b))/.test(str);`

Comment: You'll need MariaDB to get `(?` and `\b`.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Regular_Expression_Searches
I've found a working solution:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE logistic_config REGEXP '[[:<:]]6[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]28[[:>:]]'
```